# How do UserSecrets work in the Cloud?

Tags: asp.net-core, cloud, cloud-foundry

ASP.NET Core has a great feature to store user settings [securely](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html).

It works great on OSX (and Linux, Windows), stores data in JSON:

```
~/.microsoft/usersecrets/<userSecretsId>/secrets.json
```

Is it working in the cloud (Cloud Foundry) too? If yes, then were are the values stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Secrets exists for safe storage during development by helping prevent sensitive data from being storing in code / checked into source control.

> The Secret Manager tool does not encrypt the stored secrets and should not be treated as a trusted store. It is for development purposes only. The keys and values are stored in a JSON configuration file in the user profile directory.

In Cloud you can directly use Environment Variables for that.